# Setting socket read timeout with javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection

Tags: java, saaj

I am using the `javax.xml.soap` API (`javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory`, `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection`, and friends) to make a web service call to a remote server, for the most part with great success.

However, sometimes there is a problem and the program gets stuck reading forever.

To address this, I'd like to add a read timeout.

I found several ways it might be possible to achieve this, but they all seemed pretty bad.

So my question to the community is: What is the best way to implement a read timeout behaviour when using the javax.xml.soap API to make a call?

Comment: Hi Samuel

Please look into question below as it is somewhat with same context as your question.
Hope you'll be able to suggest something here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861767/http-connect-timeout-and-read-timeout-for-urlstreamhandler-with-saaj-working-fo

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to create your own [URLStreamHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) so that you can set [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) parameters like connection timeout and read timeout.

```
SOAPConnection connection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
URL endpoint =
  new URL(new URL("http://yourserver.yourdomain.com/"),
          "/path/to/webservice",
          new URLStreamHandler() {
            @Override
            protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
              URL target = new URL(url.toString());
              URLConnection connection = target.openConnection();
              // Connection settings
              connection.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10 sec
              connection.setReadTimeout(60000); // 1 min
              return(connection);
            }
          });

SOAPMessage result = connection.call(soapMessage, endpoint);
```

I have removed some try/catch for clarity.

Comment: Are you converting the URL passed to openConnection to a String and back to prevent target.openConnection from using the URLStreamHandler being defined?

Comment: That is a good point. I have not tested myself, but I think you guessed right: infinite recursion is closed ;) To be honest, I get that code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148915/how-do-i-set-the-timeout-for-a-jax-ws-webservice-client

Comment: That's funny, I think I saw that question but didn't look at the answers because it's a different problem (which I don't think that answer really addresses).

Comment: You're right. There is often a mistake between old-school SOAP API (your question) and new JAX-WS annotation based API (Zaki's answer here)

Comment: @YvesMartin Please take some time out for the question below. I'm trying to set connect and read timeout which works fine for my windows OS however it fails to work as expected on linux based system

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861767/http-connect-timeout-and-read-timeout-for-urlstreamhandler-with-saaj-working-fo

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does not work any more. Both timeouts are overwritten by `HttpSOAPConnection` (version 1.5.2) in the call method.

Answer (score 4):

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.BindingProviderProperties

public someResponse callWebService() {

    MyPort port = new Service().getPort();

    Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();

    requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10 * 1000); //10 secs

    requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 1 * 60 * 1000); //1 min

    return port.someWebMethod();

}
```

Comment: What is `Service`?  I think you may be answering a different question than I am asking.

Comment: This snippet corresponds to the use of JAX-WS annotations to get a service port to a webservice through its WSDL

Answer (score 3):

For the saaj implementation (version 1.5.2), it is possible to set the Java system properties

```
saaj.connect.timeout
```

and

```
saaj.read.timeout
```

Value is the timeout in milliseconds.