# how to set request time out of web service client(java)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, timeout

I am working on a desktop based application that is like drop box, I have a function `downloadFile(long fileId)` that download file for me from web, desktop side of the application is in java where web service is written in .Net

**I have generated WS client using netbeans**

**The issue is:**  Some times it happens that `downloadFile(long fileId)` function get stuck,

What ever the reason behind it, I want if web service function does not give any response till a given time I snatch the control back from that function and generate a new call after some time. Is it possible using java?

**EDIT** I think that it could be done if can set the request time out of the web service but i don't have idea how to set time out in the client generated by netbeans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the class `FileUpload` that is root class of web service(Generated by netBeans) there were some constructors of the class and function of the super class, one of them i was using to create `SOAP`  object. That was looking like

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "FileUploadSoap")
public FileUploadSoap getFileUploadSoap() {
   return super.getPort(new QName("http://svc.qleapahead.com/", 
    "FileUploadSoap"), FileUploadSoap.class);
    }
```

in this function i made some modifications in order to set time out parameter and this became like

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "FileUploadSoap")
public FileUploadSoap getFileUploadSoap() {
    FileUploadSoap fileUploadSoap = super.getPort(new QName(
            "http://svc.qleapahead.com/", "FileUploadSoap"),
            FileUploadSoap.class);
    ((BindingProvider) fileUploadSoap).getRequestContext().put(
            "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", 1000 * 2 * 60);
    return fileUploadSoap;
}
```

and problem solved...

in short this statement helped me a lot

```
((BindingProvider) fileUploadSoap).getRequestContext().put(
                "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", 1000 * 2 * 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the framework you use for calling the webservice, there will be some way of setting a `readTimeout` causing the call to fail with some kind of exception.

Cheers,

Comment: my WS is SOAP based and used netbeans to generate client to consume web service, can you explain how to set readTimeOut ???

Comment: `readTimeOut` is a property on the HTTP connection. I'm not familiar with Netbeans, but perhaps this thread is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536616/setting-socket-read-timeout-with-javax-xml-soap-soapconnection