# how to set request time out for soap webserice client?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, soap-client

Am using eclipse generated client classes(JAX bean class)..Any one please tell me how can set the request time out for a soap web service client?..

I have refered following links..

[how to set request time out of web service client(java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878154/how-to-set-request-time-out-of-web-service-clientjava)

http://blogs.adobe.com/rohit/2013/04/30/configurable-request-timeout-for-client-side-soap-calls/

But i could not find a solution for this..

Thanks

Comment: Did you look that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148915/how-do-i-set-the-timeout-for-a-jax-ws-webservice-client

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set Timeout for JAX-WS WebService Call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967069/how-to-set-timeout-for-jax-ws-webservice-call)