# Soap request time out not working

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

we have soap request where we have setup time out for `300ms`, when we make a request its taking more than `300ms` like `1500ms` or more but we are not getting time out exception which we have set in response.

This way we are making call

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(requestWrapper, parammap), endpoint);
```

and the `endpoint` forms in `init` method like this

```
    endpoint = new URL(new URL(URL_CONSTANT), super.getEndpoint(), new URLStreamHandler() {
        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
            URL target = new URL(url.toString());
            URLConnection connection = target.openConnection();
            // Connection settings
            connection.setConnectTimeout(getTimeout());
            connection.setReadTimeout(getTimeout());
            return (connection);
        }
    });
```

in above code `getTimeout()` function works properly and it set `300` but we are not sure why its  not working, 
 pls suggest something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting socket read timeout with javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536616/setting-socket-read-timeout-with-javax-xml-soap-soapconnection)

Answer (score 0):

The **soapConnection.call** method will call the **HttpSOAPConnection.post** which has a local connection parameter(***HttpURLConnection httpConnection***. ) that is created using the endPoint.

Try debugging this method(post) to see what is the time out for the actual connection which is used to perform the SOAP call (i.e **httpConnection** local variable inside the post method).