# How to set the Duration of a JAVA SSL Connection

Tags: java, ssl, soap

I set my Java System Properties for my secure SSL Connection like this:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",keyStore)
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePW)
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",trustStore)
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePW)
```

Now I do Something like this:

- send SOAP request 1
- doing other stuff
- send SOAP request 2

If "doing other stuff" takes longer then 5 sec, the whole SSL Handshake (Server Hello, Client hello etc.) will we done again.
If "doing other stuff" takes less then 5 sec, the request will be send immediately

--> How Can I set this duration longer then 5 sec?

EDIT:

This is how I do my SOAP call:

```
static String callSoap() {

       SOAPMessage request = //..creating request
        
       SOAPMessage response=dispatch.invoke(request)

       SOAPBody responseBody=response.getSOAPBody()

   .......
   
   return....
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `socket.connect()`, you can specify there the desired timeout. F.e:

```
int timeout = 5000 * 3;
socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAddress, port), timeout);
```

`SoTimeout` may not be needed; This timeout is the time a `read()` call will block before throwing a exception. You can set it to 0 if you don't wish any timeout reading, and you accept just waiting until a byte is read.

This should only try to reconnect when it takes more than 15 seconds to finish the process.

---

Ok, int  the SOAP world,something like this should do the trick:

```
SOAPConnection connection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
URL endpoint =
  new URL(new URL("http://yourserver.yourdomain.com/"),
          "/path/to/webservice",
          new URLStreamHandler() {
            @Override
            protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
              URL target = new URL(url.toString());
              URLConnection connection = target.openConnection();
              // Connection settings
              connection.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10 sec
              connection.setReadTimeout(60000); // 1 min
              return(connection);
            }
          });

SOAPMessage result = connection.call(soapMessage, endpoint);
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536616/setting-socket-read-timeout-with-javax-xml-soap-soapconnection) for more info, may be helpful.

Comment: I tried to build your suggestion in my Lib. I still  have the same problem: If the duration after the 1. SOAP call is more than 4 sec - the whole handshake stuff will be made again at the 2. SOAP call. Is it really a Timeout problem here?

Comment: I think it is not Problem of the Read Timeout. It seems to be more a Problem of the Http Session. I moved this to a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875355/example-for-a-java-soap-client-that-maintains-http-session)