# JAX-WS best way to handle timeout

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

I'm using jax-ws with Spring. The client is a JMS consumer application that will make a call to the server to do some additional processing including sending an email.  One situation that I have failed to handle is if a message comes through the consumer while the "server" application is restarting.  Right now the client will just timeout and the message will not be fully processed.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a [dead letter queue](http://www.eaipatterns.com/DeadLetterChannel.html) in which you'll place messages / web service requests that fail to be processed for some reason. You can now develop a scheduled service that will poll the dead letter queue at interval to retry sending the message.

Be sure to have setup your client to timeout gracefully (see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3851784/1530938) for details on timeout config) and use a persistent store (file/db) for your dead letter queue

Comment: I haven't forgotten about you, just haven't had the time to fully try this out.  The dead letter queue isn't really an option for me, but you have a good point with the persistent store (+1).