# Setting timeout to consume web service in java implementation class

Tags: java, web-services

I have a JAX-WS webservice client.  I tried to set the timeout property like this:

```
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bp.getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 20);
//I also tried using 
//"javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout" in the place of REQUEST_TIMEOUT 
//It behaved the same way.
requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
```

For more details see the question [How do I set the timeout for a JAX-WS webservice client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148915/how-do-i-set-the-timeout-for-a-jax-ws-webservice-client)

However, I'm not seeing the timeout occur. It should give a read timeout as the service we triggered is not providing a response in 20 milliseconds. We also tried to making the REQUEST_TIMEOUT value negative but it is giving the same response. From this I confirmed that the value set in request context is not specifying timeout to the service.

Does anyone know why this setting isn't working and what I should be doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

The time out value can be increased by adding "responseTimeout" paramter to the service URL. 
Ex: http://localhost.int.com/service/TestQuery.svc?responseTimeout=10000