# Can we add WSS TimeToLive request property to jaxws client

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, soapui, soap-client

I generated a WebService from a WSDL using JAXWS and import the finally generated WSDL to my SOAPUI to send out the request and view the response. For some reason, I always have to set WSS TimeToLive as 1000 in the request properties, else I get an error in the response.

Now, I generated a client from the WSDL. I wonder if I need to set the WSS TimeToLive here as well? If yes, how can I add it?

Comment: Without further checking the documentations even if something like this is possible id say it barely makes sence because the timeout definition should happen client side and best such definition could give from the servers context is a aprox. Guess on how long the server would wait for the request - but even thus this guess might be quite good the server could never know if you have for example a reverse proxy with filter or malware scanner functionality on client side which will take 90% of the request/response time anyways.

Comment: Also note that as faar as i remember you can define the timeouts in SoapUi somewhere under General-> Global HTTP Settings (something in that direction) so you dont have to set the timeout on each new soap ui project (you will still be able to override the global settings on project level

Comment: user1902288 Not sure if I fully understood you. Do you mean to say that we cannot set anything like a WSS time to live in my jaxws client code?

Comment: OOOOH sorry!!! YES you can! I totally misunderstood you! I however cant provide a solution right now

Comment: I also have to admit i overread the Security part and was refering to timeouts like described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148915/how-do-i-set-the-timeout-for-a-jax-ws-webservice-client let me know if this is the kind of timeout you want to set - otherwise i will delete my comments for simplyfication to others and set a bounty to your question as excuse

Comment: OK, is this timeout in the link you provided technically the same as WSS TimeToLive request property in SOAP UI?