# Soap request works in SOAPUI but not in Java application

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

The SOAP request that I am trying to make works fine in SOAPUI but when I run it in my java application I get the following error message:

SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Gateway Timeout

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (504Gateway Timeout

I copied the xml that my java application creates into SOAPUI and it works. I have also tried solutions I have found including updating the proxy and port in Java and I have confirmed the endpoint URL is correct. Unfortunately I cannot provide my code or xml request. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Without actually seeing your code... it seems the response is malformed for the java application.

Comment: What does it mean for the response to be malformed?

Comment: oh I confused bad response. but reading more carefully it seems that the request is never being started. This will be hard to figure out without seeing your client code. I assume your wsdl and all your server code is fine since soapui runs fine.

Comment: Also there might be nothing wrong with your Java code, just that your responding server might be taking to much time to process the request and the request is timing out on requesting end. Saying this because the error indicates towards a probable 504 Gateway Timeout which is Http error. You might want to dig into changing request timeout thresholds for which you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148915/how-do-i-set-the-timeout-for-a-jax-ws-webservice-client