# timeout if the webservice does not respond in 1 second, then return null

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jakarta-ee, timeout

```
public String getUldState(String uldNumber) throws SystemException {
    ProvideULDinformationRequest wsRequest = new ProvideULDinformationRequest();
    wsRequest.setIdcode(uldNumber);
    ProvideULDinformationResponse uldInfo = null;
    try {
        uldInfo = service.provideULDinformation(wsRequest);
    } catch (ProvideULDinformationBusinessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    if (uldInfo != null) {
        return uldInfo.getUldPhysicalStatus();      
    }       
    return null;
}
```

I would like to return null, if the web service **provideULDinformation** does not respond after one second.

Comment: maybe to add `Thread.sleep(1000);` after service call inside try?

Comment: I guess the answer is right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148915/how-do-i-set-the-timeout-for-a-jax-ws-webservice-client)

Comment: this method causes the currently executing thread to sleep for the specified number of milliseconds. And in my case, the need is not to pause it, but I would like to let it process the request, but if it does not respond after one second, i return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oneway is to use `CompletableFuture<>` to do the timeout.

First wrap your actual code to a private method:

```
private String getUldStatePrivate(String uldNumber) throws SystemException {
    ProvideULDinformationRequest wsRequest = new ProvideULDinformationRequest();
    wsRequest.setIdcode(uldNumber);
    ProvideULDinformationResponse uldInfo = null;
    try {
        uldInfo = service.provideULDinformation(wsRequest);
    } catch (ProvideULDinformationBusinessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    if (uldInfo != null) {
        return uldInfo.getUldPhysicalStatus();      
    }       
    return null;
}
```

Then call it from your your controller:

```
public String getUldState(String uldNumber) {
    CompletableFuture<String> response = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getUldStatePrivate(uldNumber));

    try {
        return response.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        // timeout, log error, return
        return null
    }
}
```

In Java 7, you can use plain `FutureTask`:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

public String getUldState(String uldNumber) {
    FutureTask<String> response = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return getUldStatePrivate(uldNumber);
        }
    });
    pool.execute(response);

    try {
        return response.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        // timeout, log error, return
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it looks right, but the problem is I'm on JAVA 7 and "CompletableFuture" is on JAVA 8 ..

Comment: apparently it does not accept this syntax "-> getUldStatePrivate(uldNumber)", it displays as an error (Set project compiler compliance settings to 1.8
Set project JRE build path entry to 'JavaSE-1.8')

Comment: but the function ("getUldStatePrivate") is called where in ("getUldState ")  ?

Comment: `return getUldStatePrivate(uldNumber);` in the `FutureTask`.